# Building Object collection taking very long

Tags: java, arraylist

What I am trying to do is build a collection of `UserObjects` from an `ArrayList<String>` that I've read from a `BufferedReader`

`UserObject` simply consists of these fields:

`int UserId
ArrayList<Integer> AssociatesId`

My current code is using a `BufferedReader` to read in `file.edgelist` and building an `ArrayList<String>` which has entries of this format: "1 1200"

I am splitting that string into a `String[]` by its whitespace and building a new `UserObject` with `UserId = 1` and initializing a new `ArrayList<Integer>` that holds any integers in the second element that has the same `UserId`

My problem is that `file.edgelist` has around 20,000,000 entries and while the `BufferedReader` takes under 10 seconds to read the file, it takes forever to build the collection of `UserObjects`. In fact, I haven't even gotten to the end of the file because it takes so long. I can confirm that I am successfully building these entries as I've run the code in debug and dropped an occasional breakpoint to find that the `UserId` is increasing and the `UserObject`'s `AssociatesId` collections contain data.

Is there a quicker and/or better way to build this collection?

This is currently my code:

```
private ArrayList<UserObject> tempUsers;

public Utilities(){
    tempUsers = new ArrayList<UserObject>();
}

//reading file through BufferedReader and returns ArrayList of strings formatted like "1 1200"
public ArrayList<String> ReadFile(){
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    ArrayList<String> userStr = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        File file = new File("file.edgelist");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            userStr.add(line);
        }
        return userStr;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

//Where the problem actually lies
public ArrayList<UserObject> BuildUsers(ArrayList<String> userStrings){
    for (String s : userStrings){
        String[] ids = s.split("\\s+");
        UserObject exist = getUser(Integer.parseInt(ids[0]));
        if (exist == null){      //builds new UserObject if it doesn't exist in tempUsers
            UserObject newUser = new UserObject(Integer.parseInt(ids[0]));
            newUser.associate(Integer.parseInt(ids[1]));
            tempUsers.add(newUser);
        } else{                  //otherwise adds "associate" Id to UserObject's AssociatesId collection
            exist.associate(Integer.parseInt(ids[1]));
        }
    }
    return tempUsers;
}

//helper method that uses Stream to find and return existing UserObject
private UserObject getUser(int id){
    if (tempUsers.isEmpty()) return null;
    try{
        return tempUsers.stream().filter(t -> t.equals(new UserObject(id))).findFirst().get();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have identified yourself that the problem has nothing to do with `BufferedReader.` Why does your title say the opposite?

Comment: You are aware that in your `getUser` method, apart from linear search being very slow, generate one new `UserObject` for every already existing one? So, if you have `n` unassociated objects, your code will create `n²/2` objects altogether and throwing most of them at the gc afterwards?

As others said, use a `HashMap` (from ID to UserObject) or (in case the IDs are consecutive) a small array for lookup instead...

Comment: @EJP good point, thanks for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you call `getUser`, you iterate through the whole list to check whether given user exist. This is very inefficient, as the size of the list is growing (linear complexity in the worst case). You might want to replace it with HashMap (the lookup has a constant complexity).

```
private Map<Integer, UserObject> tempUsers = new HashMap();

//helper method that uses Stream to find and return existing UserObject
private UserObject getUser(int id){
    return users.get(id);
}
```

Moreover, creating intermediate `ArrayList<String> userStr` with 20,000,000 million of entries is completely unnecessary and wastes lots of memory. You should create `UserObject` instances as you read lines from the reader.

Comment: thanks for the answer. definitely feel dumb separating the read and build methods as I initially was reading and building in one method. i will try the hashmap out

Answer (score 1):

Wow, you are just wasting memory and performance there.

First, don't load the entire file into memory as a `List<String>`. That is just a total waste of memory. Load the file directly into `UserObject` objects.

Next, don't store them as `List<UserObject>` and perform a *sequential* search for object by `id`. That's just .... *sllloooooooooowwwww....*

You should store them in a `Map<Integer, UserObject>` for fast access by `id`.

Actually, you don't even need `UserObject`. From what you've said, you just need a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`, which is also called a MultiMap. It's simple enough to do yourself, or you can find third-party libraries with MultiMap implementations.

Also, don't use `split()` is you know each line will contain exactly 1 space. Use `indexOf()` and `substring()`

Comment: thanks for the answer. I do need to use `UserObject` as its a requirement but I understand what you and David are saying

Answer (score 1):

You code fits the definition of a "pipeline", and thus could benefit enormously from a more judicious usage of the Streams API. For example, you don't need to read the whole file into memory, just use [Files.lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) to get a `Stream<String>` with every line in the file. Furthermore, you could do your parsing like:

```
//Where the problem actually lies
public ArrayList<UserObject> BuildUsers(Stream<String> userStrings){
    java.util.Map<Integer,UserObject> users = userStrings // Stream<String>
        .map(str -> s.split("\\s+")) // Stream<String[]>
        .map(ids -> {
            UserObject newUser = new UserObject(Integer.parseInt(ids[0]));
            newUser.associate(Integer.parseInt(ids[1]));
            return newUser;
        }) // Stream<UserObject>, all new (maybe with duplicated ids)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
               uObj -> uObj.getId(), // whatever returns the "ids[0]" value
               java.util.HashMap::new,
               Collectors.reducing((uo1, uo2) -> {
                   // This lambda "merges" uo2 into uo1
                   uo2.getAssociates().forEach(uo1::associate);
                   return uo1;
               })));
    return new ArrayList<>(users.values());
}
```

Where I've made up the "getId" and "getAssociates" functions in UserObject to return the values that came originally from the elements of the ids array. This function first splits each line into a String array, then parses each of those 2-element arrays into *new* UserObject instances. The final collectors perform two functions:

- Grouping by the Id property, so you *would* get a `Map<Integer,List<UserObject>>` with all the UserObjects with the same primary id.
- The *reducing* (squashing) the several UserObject instances with the same primary id into a single instance (per [Collectors.reducing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)) so that in the end you actually get a `Map<Integer,UserObject>`. The function passed to `reducing` takes two UserObject instances and returns one that contains the associate IDs of both of its "parents".

Finally, since apparently you want an ArrayList with the values, the code just takes them from the map and dumps them into the desired container type.